# Travelling Salesman-based question

Tags: java

I am writing a program that is based on the Travelling Salesman Problem. There are four cities in which the user determines its x and y coordinates. The salesman always starts at `city1` and ends up at `city1`, so there are 6 possible routes.  However, each route has an equivalent route, i.e `route1` has the same distance as`route6`. I have accounted for this. I've also tried to account for if (`route1` or `route6`) and (`route2` or `route4`) have the same distance.  The program tells you that.

However, every time four or even all six routes have the same distance, the program just tells me that two out of the four or six routes have the shortest distance. This is what I need help with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class CityDistancesProgram 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     //x and y coordinates of each city
     int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4;

     //Variable for the distances of each route
     double route1, route2, route3, route4, route5, route6; 

     //Since the distance from cityA to cityB is the same as the distance from cityB to cityA,
     //these are all the possible combinations of distances between each city
     double city1city2, city2city3, city3city4, city4city1, city2city4, city3city1;
     double city2city1, city3city2, city4city3, city1city4, city4city2, city1city3;

     double shortestRoute;

     System.out.println("Enter the value of each city's x-coordinate and y-coordinate");
     System.out.println(" ");

     //First city
     System.out.println("City 1's x-coordinate:");
     x1 = keyboard.nextInt();
     System.out.println("City 1's y-coordinate:"); 
     y1 = keyboard.nextInt();

     //Second city
     System.out.println("City 2's x-coordinate:");
     x2 = keyboard.nextInt();
     System.out.println("City 2's y-coordinate:"); 
     y2 = keyboard.nextInt();

     //Third city
     System.out.println("City 3's x-coordinate:");
     x3 = keyboard.nextInt();
     System.out.println("City 3's y-coordinate:"); 
     y3 = keyboard.nextInt();

     //Fourth city
     System.out.println("City 4's x-coordinate:");
     x4 = keyboard.nextInt();     
     System.out.println("City 4's y-coordinate:"); 
     y4 = keyboard.nextInt();

     System.out.println("City 1's coordinates are: (" +  x1 + ", "  +  y1 +")");
     System.out.println("City 2's coordinates are: (" +  x2 + ", "  +  y2 +")");
     System.out.println("City 3's coordinates are: (" +  x3 + ", "  +  y3 +")");
     System.out.println("City 4's coordinates are: (" +  x4 + ", "  +  y4 +")");

       //Computing all possible combinations of distance between each city
       city1city2 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2)); //distance from city1 to city2 
       city3city1 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x3)*(x1 - x3) + (y1 - y3)*(y1 - y3)); //distance from city1 to city3 
       city4city1 = Math.sqrt((x1 - x4)*(x1 - x4) + (y1 - y4)*(y1 - y4)); //distance from city4 to city1
       city2city3 = Math.sqrt((x2 - x3)*(x2 - x3) + (y2 - y3)*(y2 - y3)); //distance from city2 to city3 
       city3city4 = Math.sqrt((x3 - x4)*(x3 - x4) + (y3 - y4)*(y3 - y4)); //distance from city3 to city4 
       city2city4 = Math.sqrt((x2 - x4)*(x2 - x4) + (y2 - y4)*(y2 - y4)); //distance from city2 to city4 

       city2city1 = city1city2; //distance from city2 to city1
       city3city2 = city2city3; //distance from city3 to city2
       city4city3 = city3city4; //distance from city4 to city3
       city1city4 = city4city1; //distance from city1 to city4
       city4city2 = city2city4; //distance from city4 to city2
       city1city3 = city3city1; //distance from city1 to city3

       //Computing the distance of each possible route
       route1 = city1city2 + city2city3 + city3city4 + city4city1;
       route2 = city1city2 + city2city4 + city4city3 + city3city1;
       route3 = city1city3 + city3city2 + city2city4 + city4city1;
       route4 = city1city3 + city3city4 + city4city2 + city2city1;
       route5 = city1city4 + city4city2 + city2city3 + city3city1;
       route6 = city1city4 + city4city3 + city3city2 + city2city1;

       System.out.println(" ");
       System.out.println("The first route has a total distance of " + route1 + " km");
       System.out.println("The second route has a total distance of " + route2 + " km");
       System.out.println("The third route has a total distance of " + route3 + " km");
       System.out.println("The fourth route has a total distance of " + route4 + " km");
       System.out.println("The fifth route has a total distance of " + route5 + " km");
       System.out.println("The sixth route has a total distance of " + route6 + " km");

       shortestRoute = Math.min(Math.min(route1, Math.min(route2,route3)), Math.min(route4,Math.min(route5,route6)));
       System.out.println(" ");

       if(shortestRoute == route1 || shortestRoute == route6)
       {
         System.out.println("route1 and route6 have the shortest distance");
       }
       else if(shortestRoute == route2 || shortestRoute == route4)
       {
         System.out.println("route2 and route4 have the shortest distance");
       }
       else if(shortestRoute == route3 || shortestRoute == route5)
       {
         System.out.println("route3 and route5 have the shortest distance");
       }
       else if((shortestRoute == route1 || shortestRoute == route6) && (shortestRoute == route2 || shortestRoute == route4))
       {
          System.out.println("route1, route6, route2 and route4 have the shortest distance");
       }
       else if((shortestRoute == route1 || shortestRoute == route6) && (shortestRoute == route3 || shortestRoute == route5))
       {
          System.out.println("route1, route6, route3 and route5 have the shortest distance");
       }
       else if((shortestRoute == route3 || shortestRoute == route5) && (shortestRoute == route2 || shortestRoute == route4))
       {
          System.out.println("route3, route5, route2 and route4 have the shortest distance");
       }
       else
       {
            System.out.println("There is no shortest distance, they are all the same");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me that the code isn't quite working.  Is that correct?

Comment: I guess it could be reviewed, but OP shouldn't expect a direct or indirect answer to the specific issue being encountered. Which doesn't keep an answerer from giving it away either, although reworking the code could make the source of the problem much more obvious.

Comment: well the code does work, but its not working the way i want it to, when all of the cities have the same distances for example, the program will not say that, and as you can see in my else statement that i intended for that to happen. It just spits out two random cities. @Jamal

Comment: what are u telling me @retailcoder ?

Comment: If you want help on this issue, Stack Overflow would be the right place.  I could migrate this post over there if you'd like.  After you receive help, you may post your *working* code here for review.

Comment: okay thank you, I would like that

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ping @Jamal on that comment. It's because Stack Overflow is the dedicated place to ask when you're stumped on broken code; Code Review is for when you've got your code to work, and then you wonder if it's *good code* you've written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your collection of if statements at the end is the problem. Its a collection of elseifs, so as soon as you match one expression you're done. You need to be sure your expressions are in most specific to least specific order.

You could simplify to something like this (pseudo code only)

```
bool r1 = shortestRoute == route1 || shortestRoute == route6;
bool r2 = shortestRoute == route2 || shortestRoute == route4;
bool r3 = shortestRoute == route3 || shortestRoute == route5;

if (r1 && r2 && r2) {
    print "all the same"
}
else if (r1 && r2) {
}
else if (r1 && r3) {
}
else if (r2 && r3) {
}
// Now individual checks for r1 r2 and r3
```

Comment: @AlexChavez Now that your code works, we can review it on Code Review.